# Show errors when returning a bad request in PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using version 2.5.4 of PlayFramework. When I return `badRequest(view);` error not show in view page, my code:

#### Action:

```
public Result login() {
    Form<LoginForm> loginForm = factory.form(LoginForm.class);
    return ok(index.render(loginForm));
}

public Result loginAction(){
    Form<LoginForm> loginForm = factory.form(LoginForm.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(loginForm.hasErrors())
        return badRequest(index.render(loginForm));
    else
        return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());

}

public static class LoginForm {

    @Constraints.Email
    public String email;
    @Required
    public String password;

    public String validate(){
        if(email.length()==0 || password.length() == 0){
            return "Length short";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### View:

```
@(loginForm: Form[HomeController.LoginForm])

 @helper.form(routes.HomeController.loginAction()) {
 <h1>Sign in</h1>


@if(loginForm.hasGlobalErrors) {
<p class="error">
    @loginForm.globalError.message
</p>
}

  //input type

 }
```

When I click submit:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

How show the errors in my view?

Comment: You're returning a bad request for validation errors. That's not correct.

Comment: please tell me incorrect in code, thank, I follow document of play but not working : (

Answer (score 0):

> validate method is called after checking annotation-based constraints and only if they pass.

[Documentation source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms#Handling-binding-failure)

thats why your form has no globalErrors from validate method.

Show field errors like this:

```
@for(error <- loginForm("email").errors) {
    <p>@Messages(error.messages, error.arguments.toArray: _*)</p>
}
```

Comment: still not working, problem is validate() method? i read document of play 3 even 4 time but not working, any suggest? please tell me, thank, sorry for my english.

Comment: Problem is not validate method, is just evaluated after annotation-based constrains. Try to log your errors, when your form has errors to see if there is field of global errors.